# Junit Test case

Tags: java, testing, junit

Consider this class:

```
public class Test{
private List<TestDTO> testDTO;

//Some method which uses getTestTypes()

public List<TestDTO> getTestTypes() {
    if (testDTO== null) {
        testDTO = new ArrayList<TestDTO>();
    }
    return testDTO;
}
}
```

I am writing a test Case for this method using junit 4. 
Previously I have written test cases in which an object was being made and checked for nullpointerexception, 
But how to write it when there is no object made. The return type is an `ArrayList` with size zero.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You should write the javadoc of this method and tell what this method *should* do. Your unit test should verify that the contract is verified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to check for `null` again or an empty list.

The Empty List check.

```
@Test
public void test1()
{
    assertThat(getTestTypes().isEmpty(), is(false));
}
```

Check for null.

```
@Test
public void test2()
{
    assertNotNull(getTestTypes());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by object is being made and checked for nullpointerexception.

If you want to check whether null is returned or not, you can use `Assert.assertNull(getTestTypes()) or Assert.assertNotNull(getTestTypes())`